# How to check for specific value in database and act upon it. Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm kinda new to Laravel, and I'm wondering how I can check for a specific value in the databse? I have 5 different category id's in my databse, and I wanna do a check on the databse and act differently depending on what the category id is.

I'm thinking something like this:

```
if ($example = Example::where('category_id', '=', '1')->first()) {
    echo "The category id is 1";
}
```

or maybe:

```
$example = Example::where('category_id', '=', Input::get('category_id'))->first();
if ($example === 1) {
    echo "The category id is 1";
}
```

I also tried other things, based on what I already have working, but cannot seam to get this feature to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`firstOrFail()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) method of Laravel like this:

```
$example = Example::where('category_id', '=', '1')->firstOrFail();
if ($example) {
    echo "The category id is {$example->id}";
}
return "error";
```

> The `firstOrFail` methods will retrieve the first result of the query;
>   however, if no result is found, a
>   `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException` will be thrown

**UPDATE:**

For fetching and checking each rows, use [`all()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_all) method and iterate through each rows to get your desired results.

```
$examples = Example::all();
foreach($examples as $example) {
    if ($example->category_id == 1) {
        echo "echo here the 1 thing....";
    } elseif($example->category_id == 2) {
        echo "echo here the 2 thing....";
    } else {
        echo "something else"
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This is a step in the right direction, however, it doesn't solve my problem. This solution makes every row echo the id of the one with category id set to 1. So all rows end up echoing the id of category id 1 no matter what id they have

Comment: What you want as a result, can you tell me?

Comment: I want for example every row with the category_id set to 1 echo one thing and every row with the category_id set to 2 should echo something esle.

Comment: Right now it echoes that the category id is 1 no matter what the category id actually is.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helped me getting the right solution

Comment: @Daniel Alsaker - If this helps you to get your correct answer then please accept this answer... This motivates me to answer other questions like this :D